# What is the overarching message of "Tokyo Love Story"?

Tags: analysis, ending, tokyo-love-story

Is there an overarching message that can be gained from 1991's [*Tokyo Love Story (東京ラブストーリー)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Love_Story), specifically its ending?

What is the author/director trying to tell the viewers? Don't hesitate? Act according to your heart? Refuse/say no decisively when you should?

Comment: "How do you feel about it?" is opinion-based and off-topic, but you can definitely ask what the intended message/moral of the story is. I keep trying to edit your question to remove the opinion-based aspect, but you keep editing it before I can do so.

Comment: @F1Krazy Thx, but people can't express their feelings in this site ?

Comment: I don't think there's any rule against expressing your own feelings in the question, but asking other people for *their* feelings is off-topic, because there's no correct answer to that question.

Comment: There is no problem with expressing feelings on this site - but as you are aware from your reputation on StackOverflow, this is a Q&A site not a Forum.  The answer to 'what do you feel about it?' doesn't have a correct, or best answer really.  We try to avoid questions that are purely opinion.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not necessary to have 1 single correct answer, especially in a sub site here IMHO, I know the stack exchange sites tends to limit opinion-based questions, but still I would prefer to ask what I want to know, despite whether the question will be downvote or closed or not, `verbalism` is not a limitation for me, maybe for politicians, but not me.

Comment: While there doesn't need to be one single answer, let alone a verifiably correct answer, I'm afraid the question still is quite lacking in clarity and focus. It's really just asking "what you think about this show" and concentrating a bit heavily on feelings. Interpretations are welcome, yes, but film reviews are not.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ok, I see. SE is not a forum. Don't worry, just re-asked on Quora. BTW, thx for adding the tag, didn't expect there would be a tag for that show.

Comment: @EricWang There wasn't, I created it anew, which you couldn't do due to reputation requirements.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ok, that's a very good TV show despite what I feel about the ending, it deserves the tag, you did a good thing.

Comment: Well, it deserves a tag because it has a question asked about it. ;-) Though, if the question won't get improved and stays closed, it'll ultimately end up deleted together with the tag.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I have tried to edit it, and how it can be opened ?

Comment: I tried to refine it a little further, concentrating more on what the show tells us rather than what the individual can "learn" from it, even if that amounts practically to the same. I also tried to add that it's primarily about the ending. While I haven't seen it, it sounded like that's the case. I think it's okay in this form. It might still get a few frowning looks, as it's quite a bit broad still, but it seems a reasonable interpretation question now.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Nice job, and  you may found the TV show on youtube in case interested (e.g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3DpAUSprJE)! Though the English subtitle seems not very good, and there indeed might be a culture gap between Japan & western TV shows.